# Failed to connect to esp32: timed out waiting for packet header when flashing

Tags: usb, serial, flash, esp32

I have using an esp32 wrover b chip, an [esp32 adapter](https://www.ebay.com.au/i/183455967533?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=705-139619-5960-0&mkcid=2&itemid=183455967533&targetid=836491608697&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9071368&poi=&campaignid=7787616384&mkgroupid=85657254601&rlsatarget=pla-836491608697&abcId=578876&merchantid=7364522&gclid=Cj0KCQiA9dDwBRC9ARIsABbedBMbTQM_OJauR397AH8AATQ81NvPqB0DdYFUv_EcZj5Ro_BF_Rb2VdwaAqcIEALw_wcB), and a USB-serial converter. I am trying to flash micropython onto the esp32 via the usb-serial connector, but have encountered a few connection problems. My set up is as shown below:
[image: Circuit Diagram]Upon running `esptool --chip esp32 --port COM3 erase_flash` I am given the output `Connecting......._______…………______……………____` followed by `A fatal error occurred: failed to connect to esp32: timed out waiting for packet header`
I have all the drivers for my USB-Serial converter installed.

Does anyone know how to fix this error and flash the esp32?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any special instructions, like that you need to hold the "Boot/Flash" mode button while running that esptool command?

Comment: @anrieff, Haven’t thought about that...where I would find said instructions?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess the Boot button is on the ESP32 adapter, so try looking for info there. It's likely something as simple as "keep the Boot button pressed down, and briefly press Reset while the esptool is printing the dots"

Comment: The instructions for the adapter are given via a QR code printed onto it, but the QR code doesn’t display anything when scanned

Comment: Most likely, you have to press down the BOOT/Flash mode button when powering up to go into bootloader mode. (keep the button pressed and plug the power). Most likely the LED would blink at a different rate. Also there is a lot of fake USB to uart that doesn't work properly try another one. Make sure you use the right port and the right baudrate.

Comment: What are the voltage levels for your USB-to-serial converter? If your programming adapter didn't come with instructions then you should toss it and get one from a reliable vendor.

Comment: It’s much better to go with a esp32 devkit that is typically available only because the usb to serial interfacing is effectively done on board. Now if assuming everything is working fine and you do not have wiring issue or a fault chip, try the following, hold the boot button before starting the flash, keep it pressed until you see the connecting... text, at that point release the boot button and it should start loading the program.

Comment: Thanks @NoumanQaiser, I would’ve gotten a devkit, however I wanted just the module and not the PCB that comes with it!

Comment: Shouldn't the Boot/Flash pin have a pull-up resistor (10k)?